# Access pandas DataFrame from pandas accessor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, accessor

Is it possible to access the pandas `DataFrame` to which my accessor belongs, from within the [accessor class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor.html#pandas.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor)?

Specifically, I would like to let a method in the accessor class assign a series to the main dataframe `df` via `df.myaccessor.calc_displacement()` which operates on columns `x` and `y` in `df`.

Instead, the most I can access is the pandas DataFrame `_obj` which is visible to the accessor. But updating `_obj` does not update `df`.

From within the accessor class from `dir(self)`:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_obj', '_validate']
```

Pandas version is 0.24.2.

Comment: It would be useful to know which version of pandas you are using. The accessor behavior is relatively new and I believe it has changed over version.

Comment: [Edit] Thanks @Dave - I updated the question to include the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through public examples of accessors (eg, `GeoAccessor`, `.dt`), there do not appear to be built-in methods for this, unfortunately.